# How serving 2 different version of a website on single domain is possible?

Tags: web, hosting

For example :

when you go to (mercari.com) you go to US version.
But when you change the directory of that website to (mercari.com/jp) it goes to JP version which is completely different layout, design, userbase, payment etc.

How is it possible?

Comment: If you are using a server like tomcat there are configurations available to serve your app from different contexts ('/jp', '/us', etc). You could also use a reverse proxy like nginx to assign different contexts to different servers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.